# How do I pick an image from a set of images on my Ajax form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Very to new AJAX coding, and still trying to get around it. So far I've created an AJAX multi-page form. It's broken down into html, which contains the divs for each "new" page to display. The CSS for the style, and some javascript to handle displaying them properly.

My first page is pretty basic, just asks for name / age, and next. What I am stuck on is creating another page that has four images (small images), and the user can only pick one. How would I go about doing this? I've gotten started by inserting the small thumbnails in the HTML div, but having some issues connecting them to the JS. Only one of the thumbnails can be picked, then the user may hit continue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make radio selection with pictures use `label` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a radio button list, then add an <img> tag inside the label for each corresponding radio button.

To ensure that clicking on the image selects the radio button in all browsers, you can use this snippet of javascript (relying on jQuery) from this page: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/using_images_as

```
$("label img").live("click", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).parents("label").attr("for")).click();
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do, but didn't know you could make the buttons be images....Silly me. Thanks!